# Make label height as content in it without spacing?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, autolayout, uilabel

I have added a label on storyboard. I have given it line as 0. It's height is not static. But when there more lines then it height increased but space is added from top & bottom . I want to remove those extra space when label height is increased. I have tried using **label.sizeToFit()** but it align text to the left & I want text to be in centre. Only extra spacing from top & bottom should be reduced.

[image]

Comment: Problem is not with your label , other constrains make your label stretch . because you have give top  and bottom with SafeArea to other controls in which label is dependent

Comment: show your costraint with label. `label.sizeToFit()` may not work, when auto layout constraints are applied. Did you use LayoutConstraint to design your label?

Answer (score 0):

Edit : Make sure to decrease font size as when font becomes large , intrinsic add more space around it

contentHuggingPrioprity vertical set it to 1000

[image]

Comment: My label is vertical centre & I set number of lines = 0 & vertical hugging to 1000 but not working

Comment: may be there a margin try to color background and see

Comment: I have coloured the label is having extra space

Comment: remove the bottom most constraint of it and re run , the problem is in near by constraints

Comment: The top label has vertical centre & the address label below it has top conraiwnts from above label .There no bottom constraints

Comment: There is top view which has promotional height main superview. label is vertically centre in top view

Comment: this is the main reason of the problem remove that height constraint and hook the label top and bottom to the view

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163621/discussion-between-dhiraj-kumar-and-sh-khan).

Answer (score 0):

Here I tried following steps with SafeAreaLayout/AutoLayout to solve this problem.

**For label instance in storyboard (view controller) or programmatically**

- Remove all (existing) constraints applied on your label.
- Set all constraints (top, bottom, right left) again, with respect to its superview/adjacent UIElements.
- Set number of lines = 0 (& line break mode = truncate tail)

Here is result:

[image]

**Edit:** Answer to your query -- *my label is vertical centre to a super view*

- Remove `Top` constraint for your vertically centered label and apply constraint: `Vertically in container = 0`

[image]

[image]

Result with update (Vertically Center):

[image]

Comment: my label is vertical centre to a super view

Comment: @DhirajKumar - Is this what you want?

Comment: Yes also the parent view of label has the promotional height

Comment: Could you please share all constraints applied on label and relevant (super views and adjacent views) views, so I can see an exact issue with your design of label.

Answer (score -1):

In addition to sizeToFit you could set

```
label.textAlignment = .center
```

You could also add an UIView with constaints set like the label is set right now. Inside that View you add the label with constraints to top, left and right and the height to be greater than or equal to 0.

Comment: the problem is in height no centering

Comment: But you said "I have tried using label.sizeToFit() but it align text to the left & I want text to be in centre." No need to downvote me. ;)

Comment: Label is already in centre . see the screen shot !! . issue is with upper and bottom space with the text

Comment: Well why are you saying in your question than, that you also have problems with the text alignment? Anyway, I updated my answer with another possible solution.